# Copy files from one directory to another

Tags: powershell

I need to copy files from one directory to another location, based on the age of the file.  I also need to keep the directory structure.

This code is working as far as only copying the files that meet the criteria, but it is NOT keeping the directory structure:

```
$ListDate = Get-Date "12/6/2013 11:08 AM"
$ActiveDate = $ListDate.AddYears(-7)
Get-ChildItem -path "T:\ProductionServices" -recurse | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -le $ActiveDate -and -not $_.psiscontainer} | Copy-item -destination "T:\TECH\CopyOfDeleteFile"
```

I've been struggling with this for over a week, and I've tried all the suggestions I have seen here and on the internet.  I just need a little push to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You should put this question on Super User.

Comment: @dc2 [Why?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170798/request-for-question-migration-reversal/170807#170807)

Comment: Its not a programming question. Maybe Server Fault for server administration? But no SO.

Comment: Okay... read your link... here we go...

Comment: @dc2, if you feel it should be on SU, vote to close & select the appropriate option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those situations that is better for [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) than PowerShell (or, use robocopy *with* PowerShell). Although with robocopy, you can't get resolution down to the minute (I think)

```
robocopy t:\Productionservices t:\tech\copyofdeletefile /E /MINAGE:20061206
```

Or, if you want to use it with PowerShell to do the date math:

```
$ListDate = Get-Date "12/6/2013 11:08 AM";
$ActiveDate = get-date $($ListDate.AddYears(-7)) -f "yyyyMMdd";
robocopy t:\Productionservices t:\tech\copyofdeletefile /E /MINAGE:$ActiveDate;
```

You can use the `/COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T` switches to [preserve all attributes & timestamps](https://serverfault.com/a/288634) as well.

Comment: This solution does work, to a point.  It changes the modified date to the current date instead of keeping the original.  My original attempt, though it did not keep the directory structure, did keep the original modified date.  Can this be done keeping the original modified date?

Comment: To preserve attributes and timestamps with Robocopy, use the following switches (in addition to the above): `/COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T`. See http://serverfault.com/a/288634

Comment: I am SO SORRY!!! I found that it changes the modified date of the folders, but the files retain the original date.  I will try alrocs solution to keep the directory date.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the additional switches. If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted.